# How to post non-standard XML with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have utilities that post standard XML, but am faced with interacting with a server that requires something I'm not familiar with.

The expected XML format is like this:

```
"xmldata=<txn><element_1>element_1_value</element_1><element_2>element_2_value</element_2></txn>"
```

When I post using my standard method:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(XDocumentToString(xml));

var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml");
byte[] result = client.UploadData(new Uri(url), "POST", data);

string resultString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
return XDocument.Parse(resultString);
```

I get an error message about the XML not being formatted correctly.

When I use some stuff I've found:

```
var request = _requestFactory.CreateCreditCardSaleRequest(xmlStringFromAbove);
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://domain.com/process_some_xml.do");
webRequest.Method = "POST";

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request);
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
// Get the request stream.
Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
// Close the Stream object.
// dataStream.Close();
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();
// Display the status.
var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) response;
Console.WriteLine(httpWebResponse.StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

the response seems to indicate success, but no response content as expected.

I suspect it has something to do with the "xmldata=" at the beginning of the request, but cannot be sure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's non-standard about it

Comment: Change your content-type to "text/plain".

Comment: @tallseth what problem did you see about it? In what way would it help to solve OP's problem.

Comment: non-standard == not what I'm used to :)

Comment: text/plain == same result.

Comment: The only error I'm getting is when I use WebClient - <txn>
  <errorCode>6042</errorCode>
  <errorName>Invalid Request Format</errorName>
  <errorMessage>XML request is not well-formed or request is incomplete.</errorMessage>
</txn>

Comment: Have you tried `byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("xmldata=" + XDocumentToString(xml));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the `xmldata=`, it sounds like the API wants the data sent as `form-urlencoded`. I suggest trying this:

```
string dataStr = "xmldata=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(XDocumentToString(xml));
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataStr);
```

and this:

```
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```